# Create a special graph using particles?

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to create some kind of live graph using particles where I fire particles and change the emitter position .

The problem is that I could not find a way to fire the particles horizontal in a straight line. They seems to have some effect of snow (gravity and spin).

Is there a way to plot a particle like a line from left to right ??

```
func createParticles()
{
    let particleEmitter = CAEmitterLayer()

    particleEmitter.emitterPosition = CGPoint(x: self.center.x, y: 100)
    particleEmitter.emitterShape = kCAEmitterLayerPoint
    particleEmitter.emitterSize = CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width, height: 1)

    let red = makeEmitterCellWithColor(Globals.sharedInstance.palleteRed)
    let green = makeEmitterCellWithColor(Globals.sharedInstance.palleteRed)
    let blue = makeEmitterCellWithColor(Globals.sharedInstance.palleteRed)

    particleEmitter.emitterCells = [red, green, blue]

    self.layer.addSublayer(particleEmitter)

}



func makeEmitterCellWithColor(color: UIColor) -> CAEmitterCell {
    let cell = CAEmitterCell()
    cell.birthRate = 1
    cell.lifetime = 6.0
    cell.lifetimeRange = 0
    cell.color = color.CGColor
    cell.velocity = 100
    cell.velocityRange = 220
    cell.emissionLongitude = CGFloat(M_PI)
    cell.emissionRange = CGFloat(M_PI_4)
    cell.spin = 0
    cell.spinRange = 0
    cell.scaleRange = 0.15
    cell.scaleSpeed = -0.05

    cell.contents = UIImage(named: "particle")?.CGImage
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i also challange similar problem this code help me to get over this.I just try to decrease emission range for snow effect.

```
        let em : CAEmitterLayer = self.view.layer as! CAEmitterLayer

        em.renderMode = kCAEmitterLayerOldestFirst
        em.emitterShape = kCAEmitterLayerLine
        em.emitterMode = kCAEmitterLayerSurface
        em.emitterSize = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
        em.beginTime =  CACurrentMediaTime()

        em.emitterPosition = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.width/2, self.view.frame.height/2)

        let fireCell = CAEmitterCell()
        fireCell.contents = UIImage(named: "pink.png")!.CGImage
        fireCell.contentsRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
        fireCell.birthRate = 5.0
        fireCell.lifetime = 5
        fireCell.velocity = 200
        fireCell.scale = 1

        fireCell.color = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor

        // emissions angle stuff
        fireCell.emissionLongitude = CGFloat(M_PI/2)
        fireCell.emissionRange = CGFloat(M_PI_2 / 10.0)

        em.emitterCells = [fireCell]
```